Netty HttpClient - Capture / Log time taken for resolving DNS
We are seeing delay in Spring WebClient calls at times in our Cloud application and are suspecting the DNS resolution. What would be the best way to capture the time taken for DNS resolution? Should it be done manually by customizing the Netty HttpClient as below or can it be achieved enabling logging level on Netty transport?
HttpClient.create()
          .doOnResolve()
          .doAfterResolve();


https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/3368 to be continued here in SO
